# WSO2 API Manager 1.6.0 - What is the correct database configuration?

Tags: database, configuration, wso2

I have an installation of APIM 1.6.0 and a configuration as follows for each component.
Databases:
WSO2CarbonDB, WSO2UM_DB, WSO2REG_DB, WSO2AM_DB

I've left the entry in all of the registry.xml files that points to carbon by default, and added the gov registry configuration:

```
<currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig>
<dbConfig name="wso2registry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>
<dbConfig name="govregistry">
        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource>
    </dbConfig>
    <remoteInstance url="https://localhost:9446/registry">
        <id>gov</id>
        <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
        <readOnly>false</readOnly>
        <enableCache>true</enableCache>
        <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
    </remoteInstance>
    <mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
    </mount>
    <mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/nodes</targetPath>
    </mount>
```

For the user-mgt.xml file I left the original carbon entry and added the user db entry:

```
   <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
   <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
<Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2UM_DB</Property>
```

In the api-manager.xml file I added:

```
 <DataSourceName>jdbc/WSO2AM_DB</DataSourceName>
```

This was done on the Publisher node, Store node, Gateway node, and KeyManager node.
What I expected would happen was that all of the components would use the databases as follows:

- WSO2UM_DB would get used for UM_ tables interaction from all
  components.
- WSO2REG_DB would get used for REG_ tables interaction from all
  components.
- WSO2AM_DB would get used for API_ tables interaction from all
  components.
- I really didn't expect the WSO2CarbonDB to get used.

What I have seen from database traces is that the following happens:

- WSO2AM_DB is used by the Publisher for API_ tables. (I have not seen any other components access yet).
- WSO2UM_DB is used by all components for UM_ tables.
- WSO2REG_DB is used by all components for REG_ tables.
- WSO2CarbonDB is used by all components for both UM_ and REG_ tables updates.

The thing that suprised me was that for all components: Publisher, Store, Gateway, and Key Manager the WSO2CarbonDB was used for both UM_ and REG_ tables.  This was for inserts, updates, deletes, and selects.

Is that expected?  Or should I have removed/updated the WSO2CarbonDB to be the User or Registry database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need jdbc/WSO2UM_DB to be the database for the user store of all the comonents, then you have to change the default datasource property value to be jdbc/WSO2UM_DB in user-mgt.xml. So you don't need to keep the jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB in there.

```
<Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2UM_DB</Property>
```

WSO2REG_DB to be the database for registry in all components, configure registry.xml same as your given configuration. Then gov and conf registry space of all of those will get pointed to WSO2REG_DB.

Also note that default WSO2CarbonDB will be used as the local registry of each and every component.

Comment: It sounds like having REG_ tables in the WSO2CarbonDB is expected.  Even though it is not listed on the diagrams (only regdb, userdb, and apimgtdb are).  This is good information, thanks.

Comment: I want to make sure that it is ok that my WSO2CarbonDB is a shared SQL server instance so the Publisher, Store, KeyManager, and Gateway are all pointing at the same WSO2CarbonDB.

Answer (score 0):

You could create all the database scripts into one single database schema. Point all your datasource (master-datasources.xml) to this database and schema.

Comment: If I do that I get the following error:  ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.util.GovernanceUtils} - Error in getting the path from the registry. Execute query failed with message : PooledConnection has already been closed. {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.util.GovernanceUtils}

Comment: Is that issue due to the setting API, UM, Reg, AND Carbon all to one DB?  Maybe I should leave Carbon pointing to its own db?

Comment: We have everything into one schema in an Oracle database

Comment: How did you avoid the connection pooling errors?  Could I get a sample of your datasource configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my master-datasources.xml; it is used by Puppet. Puppet is replacing the <%= %> tags during provisioning.

```
<datasources-configuration xmlns:svns="http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration">

    <providers>
        <provider>org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader</provider>
    </providers>

    <datasources>

        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url><%= jdbc_url %></url>
                    <username><%= jdbc_username %></username>
                    <password><%= jdbc_password %></password>
                    <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>90</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>80000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>

        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2AM_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for API Manager database</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url><%= jdbc_url %></url>
                    <username><%= jdbc_username %></username>
                    <password><%= jdbc_password %></password>
                    <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>

         <datasource>
            <name>WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for getting statistics to API Manager</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url><%= jdbc_url %></url>
                    <username><%= jdbc_username %></username>
                    <password><%= jdbc_password %></password>
                    <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
         </datasource>

        <!-- For an explanation of the properties, see: http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html -->
        <!--datasource>
            <name>SAMPLE_DATA_SOURCE</name>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name></name>
                <properties>
                    <property name="java.naming.factory.initial"></property>
                    <property name="java.naming.provider.url"></property>
                </properties>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>

                    <defaultAutoCommit></defaultAutoCommit>
                    <defaultReadOnly></defaultReadOnly>
                    <defaultTransactionIsolation>NONE|READ_COMMITTED|READ_UNCOMMITTED|REPEATABLE_READ|SERIALIZABLE</defaultTransactionIsolation>
                    <defaultCatalog></defaultCatalog>
                    <username></username>
                    <password svns:secretAlias="WSO2.DB.Password"></password>
                    <maxActive></maxActive>
                    <maxIdle></maxIdle>
                    <initialSize></initialSize>
                    <maxWait></maxWait>

                    <dataSourceClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</dataSourceClassName>
                    <dataSourceProps>
                        <property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test1</property>
                        <property name="user">root</property>
                        <property name="password">123</property>
                    </dataSourceProps>

                </configuration>
            </definition>       
        </datasource-->
    </datasources>

</datasources-configuration>
```

Comment: I wonder how you are avoiding the connection pool errors.  I get them whenever I point Carbon to the same location as AM/USER/REGISTRY.  What about your registry.xml file.  Do you have your remote governance mount also pointing to the same schema?

Comment: I left the registry.xml as out-of-the-box. I use the jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB datasource specified in this file. Which database are you using.

Comment: We are using MS SQL Server 2008.  I'm assuming you run this in a stand alone on a single server?

Comment: We are running on 2 servers, configured as a cluster and using Oracle RDBMS

Comment: I'm curious how you clustered APIM without updating the registry.xml as noted in the documentation.  It says you should seperate APIM into 4 components and update to use remote registry mounts.  Any chance you could post your registry.xml settings?

Comment: My registry settings are as default, as they come from the zip file, it is using the dbConfig "wso2registry" that is pointing to the jdbc driver "jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB"

Comment: Note: The documentation you are mentioning is based on APIM 1.3 (http://docs.wso2.org/display/Cluster/Clustering+API+Manager). Clustering of WSO AM is here http://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Overview

Comment: I understand that, however the instruction that leads to is setting up a worker/manager cluster: http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29918203 which then specifies that you should create a registry mount point, after step 10 of setting up the database.

Comment: Further that guide also then references clustering by product: http://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager which then leads you to the same instructions I've referenced.  I'm trying to understand what worked for you. I'm hearing that you set up a cluster. Did NOT split up into 4 components and have a 2 node cluster with all components running on it side by side? So publisher, store, gateway, and keymanger all running on 2 nodes?

Comment: To split up into 4 components is a recommendation. And yes, we run all components in one JVM on each server.

Comment: Are your two servers all in the same hazelcast domain in the axis2.xml file?

Comment: Yes, the two servers are in the same network segment and use the same hazelcast domain (multicast) <parameter name="membershipScheme">multicast</parameter> <parameter name="domain">fon.ibridge.wso2.carbon.domain</parameter>